# При разворачивании содержимого элемента разворачивается содержимое всех элементов с таким же классом

Tags: jquery, dropdown

При нажатии на треугольник раскрывается содержимое элемента, но выходит так, что на клик реагируют все элементы с классами **"white-triangle-down"** и **"white-triangle-up"**. Как это работает - я понимаю. Но как сделать, чтобы каждый **"white-triangle-down"** и **"white-triangle-up"** в элементах с классом **"answer"** реагировал на клик отдельно не знаю.

```js
$('.white-triangle-down').click(function() {
  $('.help-text').slideDown();
  $('.white-triangle-up').css({
    'display': 'block'
  });
  $(this).css({
    'display': 'none'
  });

  $('.white-triangle-up').click(function() {
    $('.help-text').slideUp();
    $(this).css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
    $('.white-triangle-down').css({
      'display': 'block'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="common-questions">
  <h2 class="orange-text">1. Часто задаваемые вопросы</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="answer">
        <p class="green-text">1.1. Что такое супербиржа?</p>
        <div class="white-triangle-down" style="top: 7px; left: 240px;"></div>
        <div class="white-triangle-up" style="top: 2px; left: 240px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="answer">
        <p class="green-text">1.2 Как здесь работать?</p>
        <div class="white-triangle-down" style="top: 7px; left: 208px;"></div>
        <div class="white-triangle-up" style="top: 2px; left: 208px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="answer">
        <p class="green-text">1.3 Как пополнить свой счет?</p>
        <div class="white-triangle-down" style="top: 7px; left: 254px;"></div>
        <div class="white-triangle-up" style="top: 2px; left: 254px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">1.4 Как мне найти исполнителей для моего проекта?</p>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">1.5 Как вывести заработанные деньги?</p>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="main-questions">
  <h2 class="orange-text">2. Общие вопросы</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">2.1 Описание статусов?</p>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">2.2 Какой статус лучше всего купить сразу после регистрации?</p>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">2.3 Как пополнить свой счет?</p>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">2.4 Как мне найти исполнителей для моего проекта?</p>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">2.5 Как вывести заработанные деньги?</p>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="for-investors">
  <h2 class="orange-text">3. Инвесторам</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">3.1. Что такое супербиржа?</p>
      <ul>
        <li class="help-text">
          <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
          <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">3.2 Как здесь работать?</p>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">3.3 Как пополнить свой счет?</p>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">3.4 Как мне найти исполнителей для моего проекта?</p>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">3.5 Как вывести заработанные деньги?</p>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="for-authors">
  <h2 class="orange-text">4. Авторам</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">4.1 Описание статусов?</p>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">4.2 Какой статус лучше всего купить сразу после регистрации?</p>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">4.3 Как пополнить свой счет?</p>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">4.4 Как мне найти исполнителей для моего проекта?</p>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="green-text">4.5 Как вывести заработанные деньги?</p>
      <div class="help-text">
        <img src="../assets/img/alert-icon.png" alt="alert">
        <p>СуперБиржа — это амбициозный проект нацеленный на поиск и эффективное использование человеческих ресурсов независимо от сферы или отрасли деятельности.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juUGS.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juUGS.png)

Comment: `$('.help-text')` выбирает **все** элементы с таким классом на странице

Comment: это я понял, а как сделать, чтобы выбирались только из одного блока с классом "answer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

например, так

```
$(this).parent().next().slideDown();
```

Или если структура может поменяться, давайте возьмем в пределах одного li

```
$(this).closest('li').find('.help-text').slideDown();
```

Comment: лучше `closest` вместо `parents`

Comment: согласен, если списки вложенные

Comment: рад был помочь!